# How to calculate variables by factors?

Tags: r, function, statistics, computer-science

I have this dataset and I need to calculate these variables's sum,range,mean,variance etc. by group,gender and group and gender. I tried to find a solution and I found only `factor()` function to do this but I couldn't find any useful usage of this function like I want to use. Can you help me how to use this function or can you tell me if there are other ways to calculate this variables by factors. Thank you already.

```
IdNo    Group   Gender  Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8

1     Group3    Male    3.77    22.11   67.21   79.58   78.27   76.47   89.59   15.51

2     Group2    Female  3.76    19.88   61.1    71.23   70.83   76.13   88.71   15.52

3     Group1    Female  3.96    22.36   59.89   71.44   71.52   73.62   88.33   15.61

4     Group2    Female  3.92    19.04   61.00   70.36   72.31   72.09   87.51   15.57

5     Group2    Female  4.13    22.97   60.89   69.12   70.59   69.06   88.76   16.58

6     Group1    Female  3.64    18.45   57.87   67.29   66.96   67.41   86.54   14.33

7     Group3    Female  4.36    22.45   62.42   74.30   73.10   73.91   89.07   17.26

8     Group1    Female  3.99    18.39   60.64   70.71   71.56   71.26   88.85   14.83

9     Group1    Male    3.93    19.59   57.74   65.62   65.89   68.42   88.55   16.57

10    Group3    Male    3.89    21.49   63.99   73.61   74.28   73.19   86.95   14.64
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at the dplyr package, here are some links to help. Summarizing in groups: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-summarize-a-data-frame-by-groups-in-r/ . Data manipulation with dplyr: https://datacarpentry.org/R-genomics/04-dplyr.html

Comment: You can also search for Grouping in  https://www3.nd.edu/~steve/computing_with_data/24_dplyr/dplyr.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use create a list of columns to apply this function to in `vars`.

```
vars <- list('Group', 'Gender', c('Group', 'Gender'))
```

Use `map`/`lapply` to go over them, use `group_by_at` which accepts string inputs in `group_by`and use `summarise_at` to apply multiple functions to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- purrr::map(vars, ~ df %>% group_by_at(.x) %>% 
                summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Var')), list(mean, sd, var)))
```